# Why is a [[noreturn]] function checked for return type?

Tags: c++, short-circuiting, noreturn

Suppose I have a function with signature `[[noreturn]] void die(int exit_code);`. If I write the statement:

```
check_some_condition() or die(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

I get an error message (with GCC 5.4.0):

```
error: expression must have bool type (or be convertible to bool)
```

but why is the type checked, if the compiler knows that going into that function, the return value won't matter; and if the condition checks out, again the return type doesn't matter?

**Edit:** Does the wording of the standard regarding `[[noreturn]]` not address this point, i.e. relax the requirements regarding types so as to "legitimize" such expressions?

Comment: Well, function `die` does not return `bool` nor a type which can be converted to `bool` (e.g., `int`). Why would you expect the compiler to be able to convert it into a Boolean expression? The actual question should be: If **YOU** know that going into that function, the return value won't matter, then why do you put it as part of a Boolean expression???

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis [[noreturn]] is not a type at all. It's an attribute.

Comment: @StoryTeller: 1. Forgot to type in the `void`. 2. Indeed, I would have expected a `[[noreturn]] void` (or a `[[noreturn]]` whatever) to be "convertible" to any type, since you never actually have to make the conversion, so you can safely assume it's possible.

Comment: At least we can be heartened by the fact that even with optimizations turned off, [compilers will produce sound code](https://godbolt.org/g/ajVm4Q)

Comment: Same reason why `(1 || (void)0)` is invalid. Types at either side of `||` cannot be `void`, end of story.

Answer (score 4):

The concept you are looking for is called a [*bottom type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type). In a type system, a bottom type is a type that is convertible to any other type. (Also compare it with a [*top type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type), to which all types are convertible.)

The bottom type is a perfect candidate for a function that doesn't return. It's type-safe to assign it to anything, precisely because the assignment will never happen anyway. If C++ had a bottom type, and if you declared your function as returning the bottom type, your snippet could have been perfectly legal and your expectation would have been correct.

Unfortunately, C++ doesn't have such a type. As pointed out already, `[[noreturn]]` is not a type -- it's an attribute that's used to express an intention (to other programmers and to the optimizer) in a way that's orthogonal to the type system. As far as the type checker is concerned, the function's return type is still `void` and that can't be converted to a boolean.

Answer (score 3):

`noreturn` doesn't tell the compiler that the function returns no value. It tells the compiler that the function will not return.    It also has no effect on the function's return type.

In an expression, the compiler is required to check that operands of expressions have valid types.   In an expression like `check_some_condition() or die(EXIT_FAILURE)`, that requires the return type of both `check_some_condition()` and `die()` to be checked.  `noreturn` does not affect the function's return type,  so does not affect the need for that check.   If the function returns `void`, the expression is invalid.

Comment: Well, my understanding is that it should effect the function's return type, or at least the type of expressions involving the function. Doesn't the standard include any wording to that effect about [[noreturn]]?

Comment: I'd have to check the exact wordingbut the standard effectively says `noreturn` is an attribute of the function, not of its return type.  Which means that it does not affect the return type.

Comment: "A, which means that B" - A does not necessarily imply B my friend :-)

Comment: @einpoklum “my understanding is that it should effect the function's return type” — Then your understanding is simply wrong. Nothing in the C++ standard indicates that `[[noreturn]]` (or any other attribute specifier sequence) affects the type. It’s simply completely orthogonal to the C++ type system.

Comment: I wasn't constructing a boolean calculus expression, einpoklum.   In any event, you're arguing that `noreturn` must affect a function's return type, despite the standard saying nothing of the sort.   Using your type of logic, one could equally well argue that all programmers must be green, since the standard says nothing to that effect either.   As Konrad said, the `noreturn` specifier is orthogonal to the type system.

Answer (score 0):

Every expression must have a well determined type, period. So even though the function doesn't return, it must still be possible to evaluate the type of the expression `check_some_condition() or die(EXIT_FAILURE)`

And from that it follows that the function return type must be viable for use in a logical operation.

Comment: The thing is, you can well-determine the type of the expression, at least as far as it matters for executing the program: The expression's value will never be required unless it's a bool, because of the `[[noreturn]]`.

Comment: @einpoklum, You're not suggesting the type can be well determined, you're suggesting it's immaterial. Those are not one and the same.

Comment: I'm suggesting the "well-determining" of the type can be [extensional rather than intentional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensional_and_intensional_definitions#Intensional_definition), to abuse those definitions somewhat. The expression would walk like a duck and quack like a duck, so it's a good enough duck.

Comment: @einpoklum, I'm not saying you don't have a point. But the standard is what it is (unless I misremember). If your question now goes to the realm of why it's like that, well then it's asking why a bunch of people in a room decided one way instead of another.